# Compare two files with different numbers, but with same text

Tags: bash, awk

I got two files with a number and a path to a file.
The path is same in both files, but the number **can** be different.

```
--- File 1 ---
1198464 ./aaa/file_A
   6345 ./bbb/file_B
  24345 ./bbb/file_C
2345212 ./ccc/file_D
  92315 ./ddd/file_E
 452217 ./ddd/file_F


--- File 2 ---
1198464 ./aaa/file_A
   1234 ./bbb/file_B
    340 ./bbb/file_C
 452217 ./ddd/file_F
```

My goal is to print out the number and path **IF** the path are in **BOTH** files and the **NUMBER** is different.
In this case, the **NUMBER** from **File 1** should be printed out.
Expected output is:

```
   6345 ./bbb/file_B
  24345 ./bbb/file_C
```

My best shot is the following command:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {lines[$2]; next} ($2 in lines) && ($1 not in lines)'  File2 File1
```

But "($1 not in lines)" doesn't work.
How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '
    { fname=$0; sub(/[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"",fname) }
    NR==FNR { map[fname] = $1; next }
    (fname in map) && (map[fname] != $1)
' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'FNR==NR {map[$2] = $1; next} $2 in map && map[$2] != $1' file2 file1

   6345 ./bbb/file_B
  24345 ./bbb/file_C
```

To make it more readable:

```sh
awk 'FNR == NR {
   map[$2] = $1
   next
}
$2 in map && map[$2] != $1' file2 file1
```

Comment: That would fail if the file name contained white space.

Comment: Answer was posted as per the sample data provided. I know spaces can be part of file paths but it is often not used.

Answer (score 0):

*But "($1 not in lines)" doesn't work. How can I make it work?*
`($1 not in lines)` is not negation of `($1 in lines)`. `not` is seen as non-set variable and therefore it work like empty string, consider that

```
BEGIN{print "1" not "0"}
```

output:

```
10
```

Therefore `($1 not in lines)` is turned into `($1 "" in lines)` which is same as `($1 in lines)`. If you want to check if something is not in array you should do `!(x in arr)`, for example:

```
BEGIN{arr[1]="a";arr[3]="b";arr[5]="c"}
END{for(x=1;x<=5;x+=1){print x " -> " !(x in arr)}}
```

output:

```
1 -> 0
2 -> 1
3 -> 0
4 -> 1
5 -> 0
```